# Use Google Cloud Workflows to trigger Dataproc Batch job

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, orchestration, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

My scenario demands an orchestration since the jobs in a flow (say a DAG) are connected/codependent. Cloud Composer is too expensive since we only have a few jobs to run (does not worth it).

I've been looking [around](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/choosing-right-orchestrator-google-cloud) and looks like Google Cloud Workflows can help me on orchestrating my workflows/DAGs.

But **I couldn't be able to find any documentation or example where I can trigger a Dataproc Batch job from the Worklows YAML file**.

Triggering a Function that will trigger a Dataproc batch job using the SDK is not an option since (as I said) I need to control the end of a task to be able to start a different one. Using Functions I wouldn't be able to have such control.

Do you have any idea on how to (and if its possible to) create a Dataproc Batch job using a Google Cloud Workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its possible!
Since workflows are capable of http.post requests you can use the REST API for Dataproc batches ([here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.batches/create)).

Subsequently use http.get to await the execution of the dataproc job by polling its "state" until "SUCCEEDED" or otherwise